# Simple PHP tool to display arbitrary emails

Tags: php, email

Does anyone know of an existing tool to render a HTML-display for emails?

I have access to the mail-source as text and need some kind of function/class/miniframework/... to get an Outlook-like display as a HTML-page.

I looked into Horde and roundcube and I would really like to avoid having to extract the functionality from those big projects. So, any ideas or suggestions are very much appreciated!

edit: The problem here mainly lies in nested Multipart-Mails, which i would like to display inline.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to do.  If you have the source, why not just put together an HTML page and put the content into that page?  Perhaps some clarification will help others understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a combination of the [MIME Email parser](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3169.html) class and the [Ext JS Javascript library](http://extjs.com) are what you're looking for.

Specifically take a look at the Ext JS [feed viewer example](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/feed-viewer/view.html).